# How to find $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}$ for $z^x=y^z$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume $z=z(x,y)$ is determined by the equation: $$z^x=y^z$$. Find $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}$.

---

Take logarithm of the both side of $z^x=y^z$. we get $x\ln z=z\ln y$. Differentiate on both sides of $x\ln z=z\ln y$ for variable $x$. Because $x,y$ are independent variables and $z$ is dependent variable. so we get $$\ln z + \frac{x}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial  x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \ln y$$

If I replace $\ln y$ by $\frac{x}{z}\ln z$, I get $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{z\ln z}{x(\ln z -1)}$, then $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=\frac{z\ln z(\ln z -2)}{x^2(\ln z - 1)^2} $

If I don't replace $\ln y$ by $\frac{x}{z}\ln z$. And differentiate on both sides of $\ln z + \frac{x}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial  x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \ln y$ for variable $x$. I get $$\frac{2}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{x}{z^2}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\frac{x}{z}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\ln y$$ Then replace $\ln y$ by $\frac{x}{z}\ln z$ and repalce $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ by $\frac{z\ln z}{x(\ln z - 1)}$I get $$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} = \frac{2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-x\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2}{xz(\ln z-1)}=\frac{z\ln z(\ln z - 2)}{x^2(\ln z-1)^3}$$

Apparently, $\frac{z\ln z(\ln z - 2)}{x^2(\ln z-1)^3} \not= \frac{z\ln z(\ln z -2)}{x^2(\ln z - 1)^2}$

---

Which one is right? Or Both are wrong. It is confused me a lot. Should I consider $y$ as an independent variable or a dependent variable of $x$ and $z$ ? If I consider $y$ as an dependent variable of $x,z$. then differentiate $x\ln z = z\ln y$ for variable $x$. Instead of $\ln z + \frac{x}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\ln y$. It should be $\ln z + \frac{x}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\ln y + \frac{z}{y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$? If I consider $x,y$ as an independent variable. then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\ln y\right)\equiv 0$. But $\ln y = \frac{x}{z}\ln z$, and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{x}{z}\ln z\right) \not\equiv 0$. So when I consider $y$ as independent variable. We can only replace $\ln y$ by $\frac{x}{z}\ln z$ at the last step(after differential operation)?

Comment: In your problem, Z can be explicitly written as Z = W[u] / u where W is the Lambert function and u = - Log[y] / x. From here, all derivatives become simple to establish.

Comment: I didn't check your calculations. In any case, you have to be aware that when a function $f$ is defined only implicitly its (partial) derivatives don't have a unique expression, but can always be rewritten in various ways using the defining equation of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compute this derivative, you'll need to use implicit partial differentiation.  In particular, since we're after $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$, we're going to treat $y$ like a constant (just like you normally would when partially differentiating with respect to $x$).  With that said, you correctly noted that

$$z^x = y^z \implies x\ln z = z\ln y\implies \color{blue}{x\ln z - z\ln y} = \color{blue}{0}\tag{1}$$

(we're going to use the part in blue at the end of this problem) and thus partially differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ yields

$$\ln z + \frac{x}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \ln y \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $$

Solving for $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ leaves us with

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{z\ln z}{z\ln y -x}$$

Now, taking partial derivatives again with respect to $x$ (by quotient rule) gives us

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{(z\ln y -x)\left[z\cdot\frac{1}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \ln z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right] - z\ln z \left[\ln y \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - 1\right]}{(z\ln y - x)^2}\\ &= \frac{(z\ln y - x)(1+\ln z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} +z\ln z- z\ln z \ln y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}{(z\ln y - x)^2} \\ &= \frac{z\ln z (\ln z +1) + z\ln z -\frac{z^2(\ln z)^2\ln y}{z\ln y -x}}{(z\ln y - x)^2}\\ &= \frac{z\ln z\left[(\ln z+2)(z\ln y - x)- z\ln z\ln y\right]}{(z\ln y -x)^3} \\ &= \frac{z\ln z (2z\ln y -x\ln z - 2x)}{(z\ln y - x)^3} \\ &= \frac{z\ln z(z\ln y -2x + (\color{blue}{z\ln y - x\ln z}))}{(z\ln y -x)^3}\\ &= \frac{z\ln z(z\ln y - 2x)}{(z\ln y -x)^3}\qquad\text{ by (1)}\end{aligned}$$

In conclusion, we have that $\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} = \dfrac{z\ln z(z\ln y - 2x)}{(z\ln y -x)^3}$.

Comment: Thanks very much. You consider $\ln y$ as a independent variable of $x$. so it doesn't take part in differential operation. And your answer coinside my second answer(after replace $z\ln y $ with $x\ln z$ ). But why my first answer is wrong? Why can't replace $\ln y$ with $\frac{x}{z}\ln z$ in the expression of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, Isn't it a equivalent substitution ?